# Why does Search only accept YMD date format when Search Language is en-ca (usually DMY date format)?

Tags: search-results, url, language, formatting, date-time

For some reason the server thinks that the date format for English (Canada) is YMD or yyyy/MM/DD, and the server will only correctly read queries with that format. However, the default short date format for English (Canada) is DMY or dd/MM/yyyy.

This error confuses users and doesn't occur in any other search language.

I've tried changing at the HKEY_USERS's sShortDate and iDate values, but that doesn't change anything.

Can anyone give me suggestions on what might have caused the default date format of English (Canada) to be changed to YMD?